# How I can draw lines in a web page?

Tags: html, css

I intend to add some lines into an HTML table that marks grouping rows. See below picture.
Is it possible to draw those blue lines in the table? Thanks.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/kogijixici/1/edit?html,output

```
<table><tr></tr></table>
```

Comment: In my first imagine, you can trick as a `div` and set border for top, left, bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following css, and you will get your result:

```
td[rowspan] {
  position: relative;
}

td[rowspan]:before {
  content: '';
  height: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-right: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Here is the link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/juzasemeje/edit?html,css,output 
You can customise the values a little to match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.td-line {
  position: relative;
}

.td-line:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 73%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 13%;
  border-top: solid 1px blue;
  border-bottom: solid 1px blue;
  border-left: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="150" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" class="td-line">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" class="td-line">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this output ru expecting

check output in [Jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/caxiqeh/edit?html,css,output)

```
    .border{
border-top:2px solid blue;
border-left:2px solid blue;
border-bottom:2px solid blue;
height:50px;
width:20px;
position:relative;
left:100px;
bottom:10px
}
```

update ur css as above

Comment: Same as my idea. But please make it more generic, because the number of row span can be different.

Comment: @ManhLe i didnt got what R U saying?

Comment: I mean `height: 50px` is not always look good in different case. The more rowspan higher (ex >=6), the more blank space to border of `td` is. It will be better if we can set height of border relative to `td` height.